# Check if condition in another pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so called df_2021:

```
IP   isTrue
101  1
101  0
102  1
103  0
```

I also have another dataframe like so called df_2022:

```
IP   
101  
102  
103  
104
```

I want to create a new column in df_2022 `isTrue2021` which checks if the IP is in 2021 and is True in any row.
How can I do this in pandas?

Expected df:

```
IP     isTrue2021
101    1
102    1
103    0
104    0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter df_2021 and merge dataframes:

```
df_2022 = df_2022.merge(df_2021[df_2021.isTrue==1],on='IP', how='left').fillna(0).rename(columns={'isTrue': 'isTrue2021'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try `groupby.any` on df2021 then map it to df2022 `isTrue2021` column

```py
df2022['isTrue2021'] = (df2022['IP'].map(df2021.groupby('IP')['isTrue'].any())
                        .fillna(False).astype(int))
```

```
print(df2022)

    IP  isTrue2021
0  101           1
1  102           1
2  103           0
3  104           0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a sql left join here then fill the missing values with 0 as such :

````py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'IP': [101, 101, 102, 103], 'isTrue': [1, 0, 1, 0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'IP': [101, 102, 103, 104]})

df1_tidy = df1.groupby('IP').agg(max)
df1_tidy

#   isTrue
# IP    
# 101   1
# 102   1
# 103   0

df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1_tidy, on='IP', how="left")
df3

#   IP  isTrue
# 0 101 1.0
# 1 102 1.0
# 2 103 0.0
# 3 104 NaN

df3.fillna(0).astype(int)

#   IP  isTrue
# 0 101 1
# 1 102 1
# 2 103 0
# 3 104 0
```
````